# Power supply turn off when connected to sata HD

Tags: power-supply, crash, sata

Hi I bought WD Essentials 1TB and it worked fine until I used wrong power supply (from netbook) and it stopped working. I opened the black case and found WD Cavier Green SATA drive. I took it out and bought IOMAX usb connecter for sata and pata.
I tested first with PATA drive and it worked fine but when I connected WD Cavier drive (taken out from WD essentials) the power supply just turn itself off for no reason. can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you damaged the the hard drive by using the wrong power supply.

All I can suggest is either testing another SATA drive in your new dock and if it behaves how you would expect, then it sounds like the drive has gone faulty.